# Oracle find rows with multiple values in a column in a group

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find if there are multiple carriers for a part number (group). I have tried the below code but does not work.

```
SELECT PART_NO,CARRIER,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PART_NO,CARRIER ORDER BY PART_NO,CARRIER)
FROM CARR_NM;
```

Data looks something like :

```
PART_NO       CARRIER
1A3271         DHL
1A3271         MAERSK
1B0056         ALEXIM
```

I would like to pick Part number 1A3271 which has multiple Carriers DHL and MAERSK.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate by `PART_NO` and then assert that the distinct count of carriers be greater than 1:

```sql
SELECT PART_NO
FROM CARR_NM
GROUP BY PART_NO
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CARRIER) > 1;
```

If you want the full records for all such matching `PART_NO`, then you could place the above into a CTE and reuse it:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT PART_NO
    FROM CARR_NM
    GROUP BY PART_NO
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CARRIER) > 1
)

SELECT *
FROM CARR_NM
WHERE PART_NO IN (SELECT PART_NO FROM cte);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `COUNT` analytic function, rather than `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
SELECT part_no,
       carrier
FROM   (
  SELECT part_no,
         carrier,
         COUNT(DISTINCT carrier) OVER (PARTITION BY part_no) AS num_carriers
  FROM   carr_nm
)
WHERE  num_carriers > 1;
```

The outer-most query is an inline view that just filters the data from the inner query so it will only read from the table once.